# MySQL - Joining a VIEW to ITSELF

Tags: mysql, join, view, self-join

I'm working with MySQL 5.0.

I'm wanting to perform a calculation based on a previous row within a view. Is this possible? I'm assuming not because the view does not exist before the query is actually run, so is there  a workaround for this, or is creating and updating a table my best bet?

This is my incorrect coding that lacks logic, I know, but it shows what I want accomplished:

```
CREATE VIEW `Master Facebook Data` tt1 AS SELECT
    t1.id AS `Client ID`, 
    t1.name AS `Client Name`,
    t1.`Date`,
    avg(t1.`Daily People Talking About This`) AS `Avg Daily Talk`,
    (((tt1.`Avg Daily Talk`-IFNULL(tt2.`Avg Daily Talk`, 0)))/tt1.`Avg Daily Talk`) AS `Change in Talk`,
    avg(t1.`Weekly Total Reach`) AS `Avg Weekly Reach`,
    (((tt1.`Avg Weekly Reach`-IFNULL(tt2.`Avg Weekly Reach`, 0)))/tt1.`Avg Weekly Reach`) AS `Change in Reach`,
    avg(t1.`Daily Viral Reach`) AS `Avg Daily Viral`,
    (((tt1.`Avg Daily Viral`-IFNULL(tt2.`Avg Daily Viral`, 0)))/tt1.`Avg Daily Viral` AS `Change in Viral`

FROM `clients` t1
JOIN `FB Exports - Key Metrics` t2
ON t1.`id` = t2.`client`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `Master Facebook Data` tt2
ON tt1.`Client ID` = tt2.`Client ID` 
AND month(tt1.`Date`)-month(tt2.`Date`)=1

GROUP BY t2.`client`, month(t2.`Date`)
ORDER BY t2.`client`, t2.`Date`
```

Thank you so much! =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views and tables are not that different.  SQL understands a regular view to be a recipe how to compute it; and so it can join it to the same or any other view, like it could join together complex joins of tables.

Either way, there is not such a thing as a previous row.  Tables and views are inherently sets of rows rather than ordered sequences of rows.  If you specify `ORDER BY` in a query, enforcing that ordering is conceptually the last operation applied.

This does not mean that your problem would not be solvable.  You don't specify what is your data model, assumptions on data distribution and so on, but in general terms:

Let `A` be a view.  Let `col` be a non-nullable unique-constrained column that you want to order by (to use in a definition of what's "previous row").  Now look at this kind of query.

```
A AS a
LEFT JOIN A AS b ON b.col < a.col
LEFT JOIN A AS c ON c.col < a.col AND c.col > b.col
...
WHERE c.col IS NULL
```

Because `col` is non-nullable, the WHERE clause effectively says "*there was nothing between `b` and `a`*".  And because `b.col` was required to be less than `a.col`, it means that `b` is the unique record that just precedes `a` which is what you wanted.

I repeat, make sure that `col` is `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` (in could be a primary key), or this method will spectacularly fail.

This method is not suitable for very large data because of potential performance issues.  In that case you should probably assign a correctly ordered continuous sequence that will allow you to simply subtract 1 like in your question above, using a new integral column.

Comment: Forgive me, but I suppose I misworded my question! I didn't mean that I was really using the "previous row," but instead, the previous month, which happened to come from the previous row. The coding that will calculate this is already shown in my above code.

What I really meant to ask was how do I join a view to itself in order to perform calculations based on inner/left/whatever joins?

Comment: For example, how would I go about doing something like this?:
CREATE VIEW `Master Facebook Data` tt1 AS SELECT
col1 AS column1 FROM `clients` t1
JOIN `FB Exports - Key Metrics` t2
ON t1.`id` = t2.`client`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `Master Facebook Data` tt2
ON tt1.`Client ID` = tt2.`Client ID` 
AND month(tt1.`Date`)-month(tt2.`Date`)=1

Comment: @likelepers - Feel free to substitute `month(Date)` for `col` as long as the column is `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE`.  Feel free to simplify further if your months for a numeric sequence without any gaps.  I'm saying that you can treat the view as you would treat a table and it will work.

Comment: Hrrrm.... I understand that views work in the same ways as tables. So would you mind helping me understand why this piece of coding does not work & how to possibly go about correcting it?
CREATE VIEW `Master Data` AS SELECT ... FROM table LEFT OUTER JOIN `Master Data` tt1 ON ... MySql says that `Master Data` does not exist, which I believe is because this statement exists for the purpose of creating it. Is there a workaround so I can self-join this view? Blah, I just can't wrap my head around how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: @likelepers - Create two views. Create one to correspond to `A` in my answer. Create the other one to have a different name using the SQL from my answer, but do read it all and adapt to your needs.  Self join means joining A with A producing B. It does not mean joining A with B to produce A; the latter is not possible and your question fortunately does not need it.

Comment: Yep, I assumed I would have to create two. I was just curious if it was possible to do this all within one. Thanks for answering my question! You were a big help.

Comment: @likelepers - You can technically do the same within one, but a part of the query will have to be duplicated (with different table aliases) and the result will be harder to create, read, and maintain.